# Thermal airship in ancient Rome

Tags: technology, technological-development, alternate-reality

Could a thermal airship be made by the roman empire? If so how long would it take and how would it work? what are the limitations? And if it can't work, are there any other forms of aircraft the romans could've made?

Comment: "Thermal airship"? That's a term I've not heard before. I take it you mean a hot air balloon?

Comment: They had silk (from China, yay the first emergence of global trade networks!) and they had fuel to make fire. They *could* have made a hot air balloon. They didn't. Air**ships**, not so much.

Comment: Your edit changes this into a fundamentally different question and invalidates L.Dutch's answer. I'd suggest rolling it back and trying to tighten up the question you previous had, instead of changing it to a different one. (And if you want to ask a *separate question* about the airships in *Avatar*, it would help to provide a picture of one, and maybe the basics of how they supposedly work. I have seen *Avatar* but I don't remember those details.)

Answer (score 5):

The Montgolfier brothers, for their [first demonstration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgolfier_brothers#Public_demonstrations,_summer_1783), used simple materials

> To make a public demonstration and to claim its invention the brothers constructed a globe-shaped balloon of sackcloth tightened with three thin layers of paper inside.

Sackcloth is made of [hessian fabric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_fabric), which, like paper, wasn't known in those times in the roman empire.

While the hessian fabric can be conceivably replaced by other natural fibers available at the time, the lack of paper to offer some sort of containment for the hot air makes highly unlikely that an hot air balloon can be made in those times.

After AlexP comment, since they had silk, they could have used it for making an extremely expensive hot air balloon.

Looking at heavier than air, maybe they could have figured out hang gliders, but the romans had no better material than Leonardo da Vinci had, and he wasn't able to build a functioning one.

What was already existing at the times of the Romans for already quite some time were [kites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kite)

> Kites were invented in Asia, though their exact origin can only be speculated. Oldest depiction of kite is from mesolithic period cave painting in Muna island, southeast Sulawesi, Indonesia, which has been dated from 9500–9000 years B.C.

Comment: I would add that paper wasn't known in the region of Roman Empire. Chinese lampion festival have taken place since 200 B.C.

Comment: The Romans had access to silk. From China. It was expensive, but it was commercially available and in relatively widespread use among those who could afford it. It works much better than hessian sackcloth and paper.

Comment: @AlexP, good point

Comment: Da Vinci's failure is not as prescriptive as you seem to think. He was not a materials engineer, and did not have experience to guide his intuition. Spruce frames and doped cloth (silk especially) can make quite a high-performance glider. If it comes to that, as far as I know he never attempted to build any of his airship designs, so his failure to do so doesn't mean what you seem to think. For that matter, with the addition of a vertical stabilizer, one of his glider designs did work as a hang glider.